# Update WP theme without delete the old version first

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently host my site with managed WP hosting (I have no access to my file directory). I use child theme that contains only style.css file (aimed to store the customization only) and I do not activate WP editor for security reason.

When I want to update my parent theme I should delete the old version first and my site automatically changes to other existing theme which is completely different.

To upload my new version theme it takes time about 1 minute and that means users will see my site with different theme while the uploading process.

My question:

- How to update my theme without delete it first or is there a plugin I can use?
- If there is no such a way, how to show error message ("Hey we'r currently customizing our site ...") during the uploading process?

Thanks.

Comment: [Take it down for maintenance](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/). Nuff said.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the child theme then you can directly update as it does not effect your changes for child theme
and for showing maintenance there are many plugins that provides the maintenance mode functionality.one of theme is 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/

its show a template while you are in maintenance mode once done change deactivate the maintenance mode